# How can I implement DFS on a DAG with revisits, return values and without recursion?

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, non-recursive

I would like to implement a DFS algorithm on a DAG that collects information from the children and passes it on to the parents. It is allowed to revisit a node multiple times when it is connected to the root node via different paths. In my case, recursion is not suitable because the graph might be so large that running the algorithm would exceed the maximal recursion depth.

My current implementation uses a stack to manage the depth-first search and it consists of a message passing scheme in which I build a hash map (Node → List) which contains the return values of the children to their parents. I was wondering whether there might be a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: If you're simulating recursion with a stack, the complexity will be O(n*M), where `n` is the number of nodes, and `M`is the average number of messages per node. Asymptotically, that's probably the best you can do. If you want to know whether your implementation can be optimized, you'll have to post some code for us to examine.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how computation is done for a node? For example, is the "information" for a node a function of the "information" of is children? Also the multiple visits to a single node sound strange, do you need to visit all the paths for some reason?

Comment: @gus At each node, the algorithm collects pieces of information from the children, combines them in a commutative way and sends the result to the popped parent of a parent stack for that node. Yes, I need to consider all paths, but I am able to reuse the results because for a given node the results are always the same (dynamic programming).